# limitar sin usar rownum,SQL-ORACLE 11G

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g

estoy intento hacer una consulta en oracle donde requiero seleccionar los registros de la tabla con las fechas de ingreso mas reciente con la condicion de que no puedo usar rownum

he mirado que una opcion podria ser con order by, donde logro mostrar la tabla con sus fechas en orden descendente pero aun falta limitar para que salgan solamente 2

```
select*
from emp
order by hiredate DESC;
```

mi tabla tiene columnas:EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,HIREDATE

les agradesco la ayuda

Comment: La unica forma de limitar la cantidad de registros en una consulta es con rownum, o usando un where que limite la cantidad a traer...

Comment: como se haria usando el where?

Comment: obteniendo de alguna forma la fecha que vos queres, pero no se porque no podes usar rownum... como obtendrias la fecha exacta para que te devuelva la cantidad de registros que queres?

Comment: no lo puedo usar porque es la condicion que nos colocaron para el ejecicio,voy a mirar a ver que tal.

Comment: puedes limitar los registro a una fecha con `where HIREDATE < TO_DATE('21-09-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY')` o alguna fecha cercana a los 2 registros!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select campo from tabla
order by campo desc
fetch first 5 rows only;
```

Se ordena la tabla descendentemente y se toman los primeros 5 registros. Fetch first puede usarse a partir de la versión 12c de Oracle, puedes obtener más información en

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering

Comment: para el ejercicio estaba usando oracle 11g

Answer (score 0):

esta puede ser una posible solucion haciendo uso del operador `between`

dentro del between validamos que, en la primera parte la fecha maxima de la izquierda sea distinta a otra fecha maxima de la derecha para ello se usa el `!=` y en la segunda parte la fecha maxima sin mas.

para mas informacion sobre los operadores

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-6957/6n8uft4b8/index.html

```
select * from tabla where campo between (select max(campo) from tabla where
campo!=(select max(campo) from tabla )) and (select max(campo) from tabla);
```